Googl обходит страницы по протоколу http://
Сайт настроен, если попадает на http, переадресовывает https(301). Так же с www на без...

Одно беспокоит, почему гугл продолжает обходить по http, в результате все страницы помечает как с переадресацией...

как именно настроен сайт?

Возможно robots.txt или карта сайта геннрятся с хттп

Используйте, как минимум, canonical. Если без подробностей.

Тут не решают проблемы нервной системы (уровня "бесит"). Тут решают технические вопросы. Причём решаются не по фото, а осматривая пациента. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Посмотрите как у вас генерятся ссылки в карте сайта
Какие ссылки прописаны в robots.txt
И под каким протоколом вы сайт добавляли в Google?
